# Copy/Paste Several Excel Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, text-editors, copy-paste

Suppose I have an Excel file with columns A,B,C,D, and E. I need to copy and paste columns A,B, and E into a text editor. However whenever I paste the data, I end up getting columns C and D.

I ctrl+click on the column headers to select them and only A,B, and E are highlighted, but yet I end up with the data from C and D.

Here is a video of what happens when I try the copy/paste into a different workbook: http://youtu.be/rbtIrZOzaDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copy-pasting the selected columns to a new sheet, then copying the just-pasted columns from the new sheet, and then copy-pasting into your text editor.

First copy the target columns by selecting them and pressing Ctrl+C:

[image]

Then open a new sheet and paste the columns by selecting cell A1 and pressing Ctrl+V:

[image]

Now press Ctrl+C again to copy those columns:

[image]

Now open your text editor and press Ctrl+V to paste:

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: I added some directions with screenshots.

Comment: I'm getting all the data even when I paste into Excel.

Comment: I've posted a screen capture of what happens when I try this method.

Comment: This is likely because you are copying into a separate instance of Excel.  Try copy-pasting to a different sheet in the same workbook.